# Cannot access generated Database Class from sqldelight v1.4.1

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

```
16:26   Duplicate content roots detected: Path [/Users/androiddeveloper/Documents/udux_android/SharedCode/build/generated/sqldelight/code/MyDatabase] of module [SharedCode_iosMain] was removed from modules [SharedCode_commonMain]
```

Every time i import my project into android Studio 4.0.1. It shows that error and I am unable to access the objects from the commonMain package, Its only available for the iosMain Package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on master and will be fixed in version 1.4.2, if you need a fix now you can use the `1.5.0-SNAPSHOT` version and the snapshots maven repository `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots`